# API WEB SERVICE to WCF SERVICE Parameter turns on 0

Tags: c#, api, wcf

I have a scenario..

My WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I have a **WCF SERVICE**:

```
 public string AddNewEmployee(int empID)
  {
      //Code here
  }
```

I have **API WEB SERVICE** calling WCF Service:

```
[HttpGet]
 private void CallWCF(int empID)
        {

            ChannelFactory<IWCFService> factory = null;
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["thisurl"]);
            factory = new ChannelFactory<IWCFService>(binding, address);
            IWCFService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            channel.AddNewEmployee(empID);
        }
```

I need to do this way because my WCF service is already running in Production server and i need to **add** an employee dynamically using **API** without stopping the WCF service.

This code is working fine but my problem is when i use debug mode, when i run my API passing the parameter for example **44**.

When calling the WCF function `channel.AddNewEmployee(empID);`

then empID is working good and has a value of **44** but when i turn into `WCF SERVICE` in debug mode.

```
public string AddNewEmployee(int empID)
```

The **empID** turn the value to **0** what did i missed up..

Any idea is pretty much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "debug mode"? What steps are you taking that change the behaviour?

Comment: thanks @TomW.. im am tracing the code in my project if it is working or not and that what i discover. I mean running the project Using VS.. the WCF and API

Comment: Just to confirm, you do get 44 in the `CallWCF` method and that employee ID is lost when calling `AddNewEmployee`?

Comment: yes i got 44.. but when it comes to AddNewEmployee in WCF it turns to 0.. its a weird for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF service has been deployed to a production server, how did you get the WCF service into debug mode?
I didn’t understand “turn into WCF service in debug mode” clearly, and how did you verify the value is 0?
Or when you enter debug mode, is your WCF service endpoint address correct? Does the invocation in WEBApi make a successful call?
I don't understand your question, but I think it should be a simple one.
Look forward to your reply.

Comment: Nope im using the project itself.. not the deployed one

Comment: Is your channel factory pointing to the WCF endpoint address that is now being debugged locally?